# c# wpf datagrid not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to list a rss feed on a form I can consume feed  but  unable to  see the data on form.
I am see nothing. except a black form. The  RSS table is filled with  the rss feed data. Data visualizer shows rss data loaded to the table.

the xamal

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RssGridView" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="528" Width="651"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Decription" Binding="{Binding Decription}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Url" Binding="{Binding Url}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The code:
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

```
    private GetRssFeedData ConsumeFeed;
    private DataTable RssTable;
    RssDataset RssSet;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Intaltize Rss data table if exist load xml frm file
        RssSet = new RssDataset();
        RssTable = RssSet.Tables.Add("RssTable");           
        RssTable.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        RssTable.Columns.Add("Url", typeof(string));
        RssTable.Columns.Add("Decription", typeof(string));
        RssTable.Columns.Add("PubDate", typeof(string));            
        ConsumeFeed = new GetRssFeedData();
        ConsumeFeed.CallItemHandler += new RssItemHandler(ProcessessRssItem);
        ConsumeFeed.CallDownloadHandler += new RSSDownlaodCompleted(CompletedDownload);

     try
     {
            if (File.Exists("RssUrl.xml"))
            {

                RssSet.ReadXml("RssUrl.xml");

            }
            else
            {

              RssSet.WriteXml("RssUrl.xml");
            }
           SelectRssBox.ItemsSource = RssSet.RssFeeds;


        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
        }

    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 GetRss = new Window1();
        GetRss.ShowDialog();
        RssSet.Clear();
        RssSet.ReadXml("RssUrl.xml");            

    }

    private void GetJobsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectRssBox.SelectedValue != null)
        {                        
            ConsumeFeed.GetRssFeed(SelectRssBox.SelectedValue.ToString());                           

        }
    }
    private void ProcessessRssItem(SyndicationItem e)
    {
        DataRow newRow;
        newRow = RssTable.NewRow();
        newRow["Title"] = e.Title.Text;
        newRow["Url"] = e.Links[0].Uri;
        newRow["Decription"] = e.Summary.Text;
        newRow["PubDate"] = e.PublishDate.ToString();
        RssTable.Rows.Add(newRow);    
    }
    private void CompletedDownload()
    {
        RssGridView.DataContext = RssTable;
        //RssGridView.ItemsSource = RssTable.DefaultView;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you got for `RssSet.RssFeeds` when you DEBUG?

Comment: RssSet.RssFeeds shows current feeds ComboBox Name= SelectRssBox.
RssTable shows as below
http://www.asinglelion.com/lionspeak/wp-content/uploads/help.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

The column name is URL not Url

next change: 
(I made  RSSJobFeed part of the dataset. ) 
RssGridView.ItemsSource = RssSet.RSSJobFeed.DefaultView;